# Turn-Based Match - Handling interrupted turn in progress

Tags: android, google-play-services

Player A is taking a turn, and has 3 attempts to guess a number 1 - 5 (let's say 4), where the hidden number is part of the match data.

Player A guesses 3, and the game updates to let them know their guess was incorrect and they have 2 remaining. (This is currently handled locally, since calling [takeTurn()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/TurnBasedMultiplayerClient.html#takeTurn(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20java.lang.String)) to process the guess server-side would end Player A's turn prematurely).

Player A then closes the game and reopens it to see the turn in its original state, with 3 guesses remaining. However Player A can now cheat using the knowledge gained from before.

What would be a better way to handle this? Ideally, is there a way to process turn-in-progress player inputs such as each guess as part of the match data?

Comment: can you save the remaining turn in local db like mysqlite or sharedpreferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the official Android Games suggests when it comes to those scenarios:

> Your game should try to save game data for a partially-finished turn
>   whenever a player's turn is interrupted and the player has to
>   temporarily leave the game (for example, because of an incoming phone
>   call). To do this, override your activity's
>   [onStop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
>   method to call
>   TurnBasedMultiplayerClient.takeTurn(). Make
>   sure to specify the current player as the pending participant by using
>   the same participant ID as in the last call to
>   TurnBasedMultiplayerClient.takeTurn(). If
>   successful, the call stores the game data in Google’s servers but does
>   not generate a new turn notification.

Comment: This is what I was hoping to find - can you share the link for this please? Thank you!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer